# AdMob very low CPC and mediation

Tags: admob, mobile-ad-mediation

For some countries my cpc (for a banner) is less than a cent per click which I think is ridicilously low. Other countries like switserland or japan have an average of 30 cents per click so I was wondering how to increase the CPC for countries like India, Pakistan, United Arab Emirates, Thailand and Vietnam.

I don't enterly understand mediation and whether or not I could use it to increase profit.

Answer (score 0):

In Asian countries, CPC is always lower than rest of world.
According to a study, Asians spend 43 Percent less money online than people from rest world. Here I am not only talking about average consumers, bloggers, webmasters but also online marketing budgets for small and large business. Multi-National companies spend 30-40 percent less on online, and Inbound marketing in India compared to their branches in other countries. This lack of advertiser interest and non-awareness of the power of social media marketing is the main culprit behind the lower CPC in our country.